# JSON has the same identifier for a property and a field, how can I get around this?

Tags: c#, json.net

The following is a snippet of some JSON that I am receiving from a 3rd party API.

```json
    {"for":
        {
          "total":
            {"home":0,"away":0,"total":0},
          "average":
            {"home":"0.0","away":"0.0","total":"0.0"},
            
          "total":1,
          "average":"0.5"
        }
    }
```

The classes I have for deserialisation:

```
     public class For {
        public int total { get; set; }
        public string average { get; set; }

        public Total total { get; set; }
        public Average average { get; set; }
        public Minute minute { get; set; }

        public int home { get; set; }
        public int away { get; set; }
    }

    public class Total {
        public int home { get; set; }
        public int away { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
    }

    public class Average {
        public string home { get; set; }
        public string away { get; set; }
        public string total { get; set; }
    }
```

The error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

> Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'response[0].for.total', line 1, position 1047.

The error when changing the case of a property and using `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "total")]`

> Additional information: A member with the name 'total' already exists on 'namespace1.For'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name.

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Best case would be to fix the API to only generate valid JSON. Next best would be to switch to an API that does generate valid JSON. Worst case, you need to manually read whatever that is.

Comment: ...and the C# is invalid.

Comment: If you can't fix the API, hack a nasty workaround with string replacement before parsing eg replace`"total":{` with `"total1":{`

Comment: Your JSON has duplicate keys.  Duplicate keys are not disallowed by the [JSON standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-4), but they are deprecated.   Upload your JSON to to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and you will get *Valid (RFC 8259)* but also *Warning: Duplicate key, names should be unique*.

Comment: Are you certain that you will always have **exactly two** `"total"` and `"average"` properties, the first of which have object values, and the second of which have primitive values?  Or could things be more general with the possibility of multiple duplicates?

Comment: JS actually tolerates duplicate keys: simply the lastly defined values win. If you can't fix the API you can use a library that [supports duplicate keys](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1nhsB2): when enumerated, all entries are returned, but when accessed by name, works as JavaScript and returns the lastly defined value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON tolerates  duplicate keys, but only the last one will be assumed. C# doesn't allow any double properties, so the easiest way I see is to rename JSON keys.

And since nobody creates JSON manually, but computer will always create the same pattern, the easiest way to do this, just to use the string functions (or you can try regex for example).

Try this:

```
json = json.Replace("total\":{", "totalDetails\":{").Replace("average\":{","averageDetails\":{");

var jsonDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Output:

```
{"for":{"totalDetails":{"home":0,"away":0,"total":0},"averageDetails":{"home":"0.0","away":"0.0","total":"0.0"},"total":1,"average":"0.5"}}
```

Classes:

```
public class Root
{
    public For @for { get; set; }
}


public class TotalDetail
    {
        public int home { get; set; }
        public int away { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
    }

    public class AverageDetail
    {
    public string home { get; set; }
    public string away { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
}

public class For
{
    public TotalDetail totalDetails { get; set; }
    public AverageDetail averageDetails { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public string average { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "JSON tolerates duplicate keys, but only the last one will be assumed." Well, that depends on the parser. RFC 8259 says: "When the names within an object are not   unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable. Many implementations report the last name/value pair only.  Other implementations report an error or fail to parse the object, and some implementations report all of the name/value pairs, including duplicates."